# SOAPUI: Getting an response with error "Invalid username and password"

Tags: soapui

I trying to connect to a XYZ application using SOAP Webservice (SOAPUI as a tool). I able to connect the application and fetch the response using the SOAPUI.
But if i change the password in the header of soap envelop it gives me "Invalid username and password" error from the "XYZ" application. This is perfectly fine.

But even after setting the right password in the SOAP header i still get the same response. This continues for some time and suddenly it starts working fine by providing required response.

Comment: Example:   <soapenv:Header>
        <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <UsernameToken>
<Username>intsys-Ita-Outbound@tw2</Username>
<Password>Twi3!</Password>
         </UsernameToken>
       </Security>
</soapenv:Header>

Comment: Does SoapUI maintain some session cookies that are used for subsequent call.